# How can i retrive and manipulate "chapters" and "subchapters" of a word document based on headings?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

A client would like me to build an app or add-in where they can search for a word and display every chapter the word is found in. Then they would like to be able to select chapters and have them exported to a separate document. Basically a document assembler/builder but working just with chapters/sections.

I've looked into the office.js documentation and there doesn't seem to be a way for me to interact with the table of contents or sections based on headings. I guess i could edit the document, remove all sections and add in new ones where a chapter begins, but that would require a lot of manual editing and id like to automate this as much as possible.

My second thought was to grab each heading and the paragraphs until the next heading is hit, but the documentation is a bit sparse and Im not sure what the best way to do that is.

So is there anyway with office.js to cleanly separate chapters/sections?

Comment: @Freeflow How familiar are you with the Word JS APIs? They don't support anywhere near the functionality that the COM APIs do. It's not possible to Find formatting or styles, for example. If you know a way using the JS APIs, describe it.

Comment: How, in general terms, would chapters be identifiable? Are they formatted using a certain style? Are they numbered (and manual or auto-numbering)? My first inclination is to start with Word's built-in Navigation and Find panes. Through the Find pane all instances of a search term should be selectable; in the Navigation pane their location (under which Heading) would be visible. No need to re-invent the wheel and I can't imagine doing this any faster (or cheaper) through JS code...

Comment: ...If that works, then worry about selecting what's needed. For extracting and creating a new document I'd be inclined to concentrate on OOXML for the first and use the Open XML SDK for Javascript (or some similar library, maybe running server-side) for combining.

Comment: @CindyMeister  You would have to have knowledge of the styles in advance so that you can write some style management wrappers yourself based upon the font  and classes.  Not impossible, but very tedious.  And no I haven't done such a thing because I think the js api an insult to anyone seriously developing addins for word.

Comment: Please note that this question covers too much territory (it's "too broad" / "needs more focus") according to the site's guidelines (see the [help]). Questions here need to be more narrowly targeted...

Comment: Using the Office-js api you can get paragraphs from the document , then words from the paragraphs and then the style of each word. Im grabbing all the paragraphs which have a word with the style "heading 1" to "heading 4". These are Word.Range objects so i should be able to grab their .parentBody and isolate "chapters" that way. My main concern is whether the .parentBody will contain all the text from the chapter and how it behaves with "sub-chapters". I really wish there was a way to create a custom range between 2 search terms.

Answer (score 0):

The following loops over paragraphs and looks for words with the style heading 1 or heading 2 and adds their ranges to headingRanges[].

headingRanges[] is later looped over and a new range, deltaRange, is created by expanding each heading range to the start of the following heading. 
I then output the deltaRange's text to console.

This chops up chapters with sub-chapters in them, but if that functionality is necessary it shouldn't be too difficult to build on top of this.

```
let headings = [];
let headingRanges = [];

Word.run(async context => {
    let paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;

    context.load(paragraphs, ["items"]);
    await context.sync();

    for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; ++i) {
        let item = paragraphs.items[i];

        context.load(item, ["text", "style", "styleBuiltIn"]);
        await context.sync();

        if ( item.style === "heading 1" || item.style === "heading 2"){
            //console.log("(" + item.style + ")\n" + item.text);
            headings.push(item.text);
            let itemRange = item.getRange("start");
            itemRange.track();
            headingRanges.push(itemRange);
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < headingRanges.length-1; i++){
        let deltaRange = headingRanges[i].expandTo(headingRanges[i+1]);
        let chapterText = deltaRange.text;
        await context.sync();
        console.log(chapterText);
    }
});
```

I'm now having issues with keeping track() of ranges and having Word.run() use that ranges context, but ill make a separate post for that.